# R: Set consistent index values after executing rbind()

Tags: r

I have two one-column data frames and I want to append the second dataframe to the first one. I'm using rbind(), but the results come out in an unclear ordering.

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
Boston <- BostonHousing

col <- Boston[1]
col_t <- Boston[1]^.5

Column <- rbind(col,col_t)
```

The first 506 rows is exactly what you might expect. It is the vector for `col` with the index values in order. That's the number of rows for `col`

Everything past 506 is where things get weird

```
500   0.1778300
501   0.2243800
502   0.0626300
503   0.0452700
504   0.0607600
505   0.1095900
506   0.0474100
1100  0.3631980
2100  0.4867034
3100  0.4866320
4100  0.5035337
510   0.5859125
610   0.4954375
710   0.6154352
810   0.6792093
910   0.7327490
1010  0.7016333
1110  0.7419831
1210  0.6516065
1310  0.6229053
1410  0.9116644
```

It continues like that through to the end. Here is the end

```
4921  0.6380399
4931  0.6446361
4941  0.7043114
4951  0.7749936
4961  0.7088686
4971  0.7804763
4981  0.7686879
4991  0.7511440
5001  0.7079474
5011  0.7416463
5021  0.5745879
5031  0.5384707
5041  0.5711150
5051  0.6426199
5061  0.5434680
```

It has the right number of rows, but the index goofiness makes me suspicious that rbind simply appended `col_t` to the end of `col`.

Comment: Does `rbind(col, col_t, make.row.names=FALSE)` give you what you want?

Comment: Beautiful. It does